# ‘play music’ en Esperanto

Tags: phrase-requests

Mi demandas min kiel diri ‘to play music’ en Esperanto en tiuj ĉi kuntekstoj:

- muziki per muzikinstrumento
- fari ke muziko sonas el laŭtparolilo (ekz. el KD)

Ĉu oni vere diras ‘ludi muzikon’? Tiu iomete ŝajnas al mi anglismo.

Answer (score 2):

Jes, oni diras *ludi muzikon*.  Eĉ PIV diras ke *ludi* ankaŭ signifas *Uzi muzikilon* aŭ *Aŭdigi muzikaĵon per muzikilo*.

Ne estas nur anglismo.  Mi ne konas tiom multe da lingvoj, sed en la Ĉeĥa, ni uzas la samajn vortojn, *hrát muziku*.

Comment: Eble mi pli bone diru ‘eŭropismo’. Mi pensas ke ‘ludi muzikon’ estas tute malsama afero ol ‘ludi muzikon’, precipe per laŭtparolilo Tial mi konjektis ke en Esperanto, oni uzus ian pli laŭvortan frazon kiel ‘sonigi muzikon’.

Answer (score 0):

Jes, oni diru "ludi muzikon".

> Muziki per instrumento por sin distri aŭ distri aliajn: Petro ...
>   penis ludi sur la gitaro ... valson [1]; ludi violononZ; gloru la
>   Eternulon ..., per dekkorda psaltero ludu al Li [2].

http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/lud.html#lud.0i